# Using Array Elements as Function Arguments

Tags: functions, variable

Suppose I have an array

```
p = {a,b,c,d}
```

and a function f that takes a variable number of arguments.  I want to evaluate

```
f[a,b,c,d]
```

It won't do to type

```
f[p]
```

because this returns the array `{f[a],f[b],f[c],f[d]}`
 which is not at all the right thing.

How do I get f to accept the elements of p (as opposed to p itself) as arguments?

Edited to add:  Per a request in comments, here is a concrete example.  Suppose p={2,3,4}.  I would like an expression that returns Multinomial[2,3,4], which is to say 1260.  It doesn't work to type Multinomial[p], because this gives {Multinomial[2],Multinomial[3],Multinomial[4]}={1,1,1}, which is not at all the same as 1260.

Comment: Try evaluating `p = {p[1], p[2]}`, you won't be able to because it will start an endless recursion that will be capped by the recursion limit.

Comment: Please provide a more concrete example, *including* the definition of the function 'f'. It is unclear at this point what you're looking for.

Comment: Pickett:  Sorry; I chose a bad name for the array.  I'm editing to fix this.  The problem remains.

Comment: @rasher:  How about taking f=Multinomial ?

Comment: @WillO: Please, edit your question to include the function, and what it does vs what you expect (or need). Using `f=Multinomial` against your updated `p` definition returns precisely what's expected...

Comment: @rasher:  I do believe the question is clear as stated, but at your request, I will edit with a concrete example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is really easy if you understand the internal form of `{a,b,c,d}`. Let's look at it:

```
p={a,b,c,d};
FullForm[p]
(* List[a,b,c,d] *)
```

as you see what you want is not really far away because basically, you only need to replace `List` with `f`. This is exactly what `Apply` (or as operator `@@`) does:

```
f @@ p
(* f[a, b, c, d] *)
```

Comment: This is crystal clear.  All I asked for was a solution, but you gave me both a solution and an understanding, so thank you doubly.

Comment: @ halirutan Isn't is nice when someone ask a question about something that Mathematica was beautifully designed to do.

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe Indeed and it is even nicer for the user, because it lets him understand some of the mystifying operators like `@@` or `@@@` very naturally.

Comment: This does not necessarily answer the question if the function `f` requires extra parameters. What if I need `f[a,b,c,d,n]`, like in the `Join` function? There is no other way but appending `n` to the list?

Comment: I.e. anything better than the slightly cryptic `Join @@ Join[p, {n}]`

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear.

```
a = {p[1], p[2], p[3]}

f[x__] := 2 x

f[a]
```

(* or *)

```
f /@ a
```

(* or *)

```
Thread[f[a]]
```

yields, e.g. `{2 p[1], 2 p[2], 2 p[3]}`

Note also I used `a` for the vector, else recursion...

If you just want to transmute the vector into an argument list:

```
f[Sequence @@ p]
```

Comment: I am sorry the question wasn't clear.  I don't think your answer helps with the intended question.  What I want to get is f[p[1],p[2],p[3]], not {f[p[1],f[p[2]],f[p[3]}.  (I've changed the p[1] etc to a,b,c in the question statement.)

Comment: @WillO: see latter part of answer

Comment: That works!  Thank you.

Comment: @WillO: Good, note you can also use `Apply` (or `f@@` as shorthand) to do similar, if it fits with your definitions.