# How to call a function with an arbitrary list as its arguments inside a functional?

Tags: functions, variable, functional

I have the following functional defined (i.e. a function of another function) where `variableList` contains the variable (arguments if you wish) of the `function`. How can I use this list to call `function`?

```
functional[function_, variableList_]:= function[variableList]+variableList[[1]]
```

It is illegal to feed `variableList` as the input for the function since it only accept `function[i, j, k, l]` format and not `function[{i, j, k, l}]`, for instance. This list is much much larger than the example here, hence, I am looking for a clever method to find out how I should resolve this issue without changing the arguments of the functional.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43550/using-array-elements-as-function-arguments?rq=1). Basically I should use `function @@ variableList`.